# Preventing multiple entries in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code populates a list of users that do not belong in an existing list 'selectedUsers'.

```
foreach (var childOrg in viewModel.ChildOrganizations)
{
    List<OrganizationUserViewModel> childOrgUsers = new List<OrganizationUserViewModel>();
    var users = this._organizationManager.GetOrganizationUsers(childOrg.OrganizationId);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var userViewModel = Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>(user.User);
        userViewModel.Organization_UserId = user.Organization_UserId;
        if (selectedUsers != null)
        {
            foreach (OrganizationUserViewModel selectedUser in selectedUsers)
            {
                if (selectedUser.UserId != userViewModel.UserId)
                {
                    childOrgUsers.Add(userViewModel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    childOrg.Users = childOrgUsers;
}
```

This works fine if only one user exists within 'selectedUsers', but if there are a number of entries, multiple additions are made to the new list as a result of the foreach loop. How would I avoid this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** I have just read through my question and I should probably clarify as I really haven't made it clear. As the foreach runs for each entry in the list, it is also adding entries for the selected users when the ID doesn't match up with the current entry in userViewModel. These are what I really need to focus on removing, as I want anything that is stored in selectedUsers to be absent from userViewModel. Sorry for the lack of clarification!

Comment: Have you tried using Distinct?... childOrg.Users = childOrgUsers.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried Distinct and while it successfully removes duplicates, there remains an entry for the selected users. I have just read through my question and I should probably clarify as I really haven't made it clear. As the foreach runs for each entry in the list, it is also adding entries for the selected users when the ID doesn't match up with the current entry in userViewModel. These are what I really need to focus on removing, as I want anything that is stored in selectedUsers to be absent from userViewModel. Sorry for the lack of clarification!

Comment: Add that clarification to your question, so others won't have to ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I think I understand what you need now.  Give this a try.

```
foreach (var childOrg in viewModel.ChildOrganizations)
{
    List<OrganizationUserViewModel> childOrgUsers = new List<OrganizationUserViewModel>();
    var users = this._organizationManager.GetOrganizationUsers(childOrg.OrganizationId);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var userViewModel = Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>(user.User);
        userViewModel.Organization_UserId = user.Organization_UserId;
        if (selectedUsers != null)
        {
            var foundUser = selectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userViewModel.UserId);

            if(foundUser == null)
            {
                childOrgUsers.Add(userViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
    childOrg.Users = childOrgUsers.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you need something like `ExceptBy`

```
childOrg.Users = users.ExceptBy(selectedUsers, u=>u.UserId)
```

---

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExceptBy<T, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<T> list1,
        IEnumerable<T> list2,
        Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(list2.Select(x => keySelector(x)));
        return list1.Where(x => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(x)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understand the question.
Cache all the user id you retrieve from your method `Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>`, and then, add the missing one to your list:

```
foreach (var childOrg in viewModel.ChildOrganizations)
{
    var allUserId = new HashSet<int>();
    var users = this._organizationManager.GetOrganizationUsers(childOrg.OrganizationId);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var userViewModel = Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>(user.User);
        userViewModel.Organization_UserId = user.Organization_UserId;
        allUserId.Add(userViewModel.UserId);
    }

    var childOrgUsers = new List<OrganizationUserViewModel>();
    if (selectedUsers != null)
    {
        foreach (OrganizationUserViewModel selectedUser in selectedUsers)
        {
            if(allUserId.Contains(selectedUser.UserId) == false)
            {
                childOrgUsers.Add(userViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
    childOrg.Users = childOrgUsers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick suggestion! This is great and removes all of the duplicate entries, but there is an issue as selected users are still in being saved in the userViewModel. I have made an amendment to my original question which outlines this, but I would like any entry in the selectedUsers list to be omitted from the userViewModel. How would I go about this? Thanks again for your time.